# Querying realtime database with exact value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this code

```
Database.database().reference()
        .child("messages")
        .queryEqual(toValue: "bIXp9l08Lpg6jfKBMy45dKj5bNq1_g5dhCjncvsSiTfxStCMdruLsPvC3")
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                print("here")
                print(snap)
                // snap.ref.removeValue()
            }
        })
```

and my database is structured like this:

[image]

I can't workout for the life of me why I am getting nulls when I am querying this. Like this is the exact thing I want to query, but I've hard coded it to just check I'm not going crazy, in actual fact I want to query but the start of the id using the .startsWith function, but I can't seem to get the value even like this, I've completely relaxed all of my firebase rules too so that shouldn't be an issue, both .read and .write are set to true at the minute within the messages node.

Answer (score 0):

Queries in Firebase Realtime Database always consist of two parts:

1. an instruction to order the child nodes on a specific value.
2. an instruction to then filter the data on those values.

Your code only contains the latter, which means that Firebase actually orders the data on a very old `.priority` value, which you're unlikely to use.

So to make your code work, first call `queryOrderedByKey()`:

```
Database.database().reference()
        .child("messages")
        .queryOrderedByKey() // 
        .queryEqual(toValue: "bIXp9l08Lpg6jfKBMy45dKj5bNq1_g5dhCjncvsSiTfxStCMdruLsPvC3")
```

Comment: Great explanation Frank! Do you think that could be incorporated into an error message when people try to do #2 without #1? Certainly happened to me!

Comment: The problem is that for backwards compatibility the call sequence you do is actually valid. If you nodes had a `.priority` it would work. So we can't throw an error in this case, as you might want that exact behavior. You're not the only one to bump into this problem though, so we'll keep monitoring and considering if we can have a single API that allows both the legacy `.priority` values and for the more modern orderings.